# Unable to include HTTPSClientSession

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

***Preparation***

I added poco to my project using:

```
git clone --recurse-submodules https://github.com/pocoproject/poco.git ThirdParty/poco
```

So my project structure looks like this:

```
ThirdParty/poco
include/
src/
main.cpp
CMakeLists.txt
```

My CMakeLists looks something like this :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13.4 FATAL_ERROR)
project(sample)
set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake)
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/ThirdParty/poco)
add_executable(runservice main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(runservice PUBLIC ${PROJECT_NAME} Poco::Net)
```

My main looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Poco/Net/HTTPClientSession.h>
#include <Poco/Net/HTTPSClientSession.h>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    //Code here

    return 0;
}
```

***Errors***

I am able to include HTTPClientSession as <Poco/Net/HTTPClientSession.h> but when I include <Poco/Net/HTTPSClientSession.h>, it gives me the following error : fatal error: 'Poco/Net/HTTPSClientSession.h' file not found

Am I missing something in CMakeLists? I checked that HTTPSClientSession is not present in 'poco/Net', instead it's under 'poco/NetSSL_OpenSSL'.
So I tried to add Poco::NetSSL_OpenSSL to my target_include_libraries but then cmake is unable to generate build files correctly.

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You need [include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include_directories.html).

I'd also suggest to enclose the include paths in double quotes, rather than angle brackets.

But ... you'll be much better off starting with the [cmake example](https://github.com/pocoproject/cmake-sample), which will automagically take care of everything.

EDIT:

For cmake example:

```
target_link_libraries(pocoex PUBLIC Poco::Foundation Poco::XML Poco::JSON Poco::Util Poco::Net Poco::Crypto Poco::NetSSL)
```

Comment: I switched my cmake to the sample in your link. The problem remains. I can include <Poco/Net/HTTPClientSession.h> but not <Poco/Net/HTTPSClientSession.h>. It still says  fatal error: 'Poco/Net/HTTPSClientSession.h' file not found

Comment: you are talking about two classes from two different libraries (with headers in two different directories) - one is Poco::Net, the other is Poco::NetSSL_OpenSSL (or Poco:NetSSL_Win)

Comment: Yes, I get that. So, my first step was to add  Poco::NetSSL_OpenSSL to target_link_libraries(runservice PUBLIC ${PROJECT_NAME} Poco::Net Poco::NetSSL_OpenSSL). When I do this CMake generate step fails. It says Target "runservice" links to target "Poco::NetSSL_OpenSSL" but the target
  was not found. Which makes sense because NetSSL_OpenSSL isn't built as a target. I can't include <Poco/NetSSL_OpenSSL/HTTPSClientSession.h> either. It throws the same header not found error. Do I have to add include_directories with the new cmake. If so, how does <Poco/Net/HttpClientSession.h> works fine?

Comment: Well, the cmake developer has named the library NetSSL. So, you need Poco::NetSSL in target_link_libraries. 
Try this:
target_link_libraries(pocoex PUBLIC Poco::Foundation Poco::XML Poco::JSON Poco::Util Poco::Net Poco::Crypto Poco::NetSSL)

Comment: I am sorry to bring this up again but neither Crypto nor NetSSL are built as targets. Running cmake command with the above target_link_libararies gives the same thing:  target "runservice" links to target "Poco::NetSSL" but the target was not
  found.  Perhaps a find_package() call is missing for an IMPORTED target, or
  an ALIAS target is missing? Same for Crypto

Comment: Okay, this is fixed now. Apparently, there was a cmake cache issue because I removed the build directory and ran a fresh cmake and it works. Thank you for your time!